# Entity Framework Core Save foreign key value after deletion of primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello I would like to ask is it possible to save foreign key value (e.g. history of orders) after deletion a primary key (eg. user of shop) using Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Please Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to override the SaveChanges method then search for the states which are EntityState.Deleted.